# How to map a JSON which contains a key whichs value is an array in Spring MVC via @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I try to map the following JSON to be received by my Spring MVC Controller:

```
{
 "name" : "toolOne",
 "parameters" : ["abc", "def"]
}
```

The Class I want to map it to is the following:

**Tool.java**

```
public class Tool {                                         

  private String name;                                      
  private List<String> parameters;     // not working                     

  public Tool(String name, List<String> parameters) {       
    this.name = name;                                       
    this.parameters = parameters;                           
  }                                                         
}
```

And this is the handler
**ToolExecutorController.java**

```
@RestController
public class ToolExecutorController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/toolbox/execute", method = POST,
          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
          produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
  public String handleExecutionRequest(@RequestBody Tool tool) {
    return "thanks";
  }
}
```

Following Spring-Error log occurs:

```
2017-02-03 18:21:13.381  WARN 10940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.abc.toolbox.components.rest.Tool: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7e2445fa; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.abc.toolbox.components.rest.Tool: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7e2445fa; line: 1, column: 1]
2017-02-03 18:21:13.381  WARN 10940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.abc.toolbox.components.rest.Tool: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7e2445fa; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.abc.toolbox.components.rest.Tool: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7e2445fa; line: 1, column: 1]
2017-02-03 18:21:13.398  WARN 10940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

I'd love to have the array of *parameters* mapped to my Java object. What am I missing here?

Comment: add an empty constructor and add public getter setter for those two variables

Comment: that did not changed anything. It worked with only having the "name" field in the Tool.java class. So I don't think a missing empty CTOR and Getter/setter missing was the issue

Comment: Read the line 2 of your error message **an not construct instance of com.abc.toolbox.components.rest.Tool: no String-argument constructor**

Comment: tells me only String Types can be mapped?

Comment: just add Empty constructor.

Comment: as I said - does not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must need a no-argument constructor for Tool.class and then either you need getter setter for the attributes or you can set @JsonProperty meta-data like below:

```
public class Tool {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("parameters")
    private List<String> parameters;

    public Tool() {
    }

    public Tool(String name, List<String> parameters) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }       
}
```